# Excel-Protection from one sheet is set in another

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I created an excel file dynamicly using openXML. Inside this sheet there are multiple sheets. Inside each sheet there can be rows that are write-protected.

I use an excel file as template. In this template there are "normal" rows which allow editing and a row that does not. I grab the row and copy it to the places where I do not want the user to be able to edit the contents:

```
private Row CloneRow(Row sourceRow, uint index, bool? hidden = null)
{
    var targetRow = (Row) sourceRow.CloneNode(true);
    if (hidden.HasValue)
    {
        targetRow.Hidden = hidden;
    }

    foreach (Cell cell in targetRow.Elements<Cell>())
    {
        // Update the references for reserved cells.
        string cellReference = cell.CellReference.Value;
        cell.CellReference = new StringValue(cellReference.Replace(targetRow.RowIndex.Value.ToString(), index.ToString()));
        cell.CellFormula = null;
    }
    // Update the row index.
    targetRow.RowIndex = new UInt32Value(index);

    return targetRow;
}
```

the parameter sourceRow is read from the template:

```
List<Row> rows = sheet.ChildElements.OfType<Row>().ToList();
rowChangeAllowed=rows.FirstOrDefault(rw=>rw.RowIndex==3);
rowNotChangeAllowed=rows.FirstOrDefault(rw=>rw.RowIndex==4);
```

Everything works as expected. But when I open the file in Excel, rows that should be proteced on ANY sheet are protected on ALL sheets.

Example:
Sheet 1: Row 4+5 should be protected
Sheet 2: Row 7 should be protected.

Now on sheet 1 rows 4,5 and 7 are protected

When I switch to the second sheet, suddenly everything works as needed: On Sheet 1, row 4+5 are still protected, but row 7 is not.

Because the behaviour is only wrong directly after opening the file, but is correct when I switch between the sheets: Is there an additional command I have to call to "refresh" the file after creating?

Additional Issue:
When I change a cell in sheet 1, it also is automaticly changed in sheet 2 (again: until I swap the sheets once manually)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was having to many views in the sheet. The following code solved the issue:

```
//There can only be one sheet that has focus
SheetViews views = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetViews>();
if (views != null)
{
views.Remove();
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
}
```

(got it from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/02/19/how-to-copy-a-worksheet-within-a-workbook.aspx)